# How to get req.user.email in NodeJS + Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, request, passport.js

I am using NodeJS, Express 4 with PassportJS for authentication.
Earlier when I was using Express 3 I could access the authenticated users email (which is used by PassportJS for signup) by doing:

```
req.user.local.email
```

With Express 3 I used the following structure:

```
app.configure(function() {

    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
...
});
```

This is now deprecated in Express 4 and I not sure how to access the authenticated users registered email now.

I tried req.body.email but it's 'undefined'.

I have `body-parser` installed.

```
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Could somebody please help me with how to get this information from the request.

Also, I would appreciate if someone can direct me to a reference as to how Passport.js stores this information.

Comment: Can you update your question with the whole code snippet where you are initializing body parser ? Also, the form code using which you are posting the data

Comment: Normal I'm not doing anything else with the 'bodyParser'. Do I need to initialize in some way?

Comment: I am a bit unsure until I see the whole code.

Comment: To answer one of your questions, it's up to you how passport stores user information: http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/ which is why we need to see the rest of your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official documentation: http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

Here you can find a very detailed tutorial, working with Express 4: [Scotch.io Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)

And here, there is some porting instructions from Express 3 to Express 4, by the same authors from above: [Porting to Express 4](https://scotch.io/tutorials/upgrading-our-easy-node-authentication-series-to-expressjs-4-0)

Good luck!